# Time complexity of function minimizers for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, optimization, training

I am trying to train a `neural network` for recognizing handwritten letters from A to J . I have a training set of size 200000 . Each training set is a list of  784 pixel values. My neural net has `input layer of size 784` , `hidden layer of size 50` and `output layer of size 10`.

I am using **fmin_cg minimization** function of `scipy` library of python. The problem I am facing is that each iteration is taking a lot of time.

- The first iteration took almost 7-10 minutes.
- The second iteration took 20 minutes.
- Third is still running.

This might be due to my outdated computer with only 2 gb of memory and a slow processor but I have previously trained a neural net with the `training set of size 5000` , `input layer size if 400` , `hidden layer size 25` and the `output layer of size 10` . This neural net recognized handwritten digits and it was an exercise problem of coursera course on machine learning by Andrew Ng .

So  yes I know that the current neural network should take more time to train than the previous one as the training set , input layer, and hidden layer are all much larger than previous neural net but still, I think it's taking a lot of time . Why is it so slow ?

Is it normal for the neural network of this size ? Or should I use other faster optimization algorithm ? Is there a way to measure time complexity of neural networks ?

Comment: Try SGD instead of conjugate gradient descent (fmin_cg).

Comment: @Emre Yes I have read about SGD and found out that it is more appropriate for this case . But I want to know whether SGD is always used whenever the training set is large ? Or there are only specific cases where SGD is used ?

Comment: Variants of SGD, often with minibatches, are the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural networks are best trained with stochastic gradient descent (with minibatches), not with conjugate gradient descent or other optimization methods.

I recommend using a framework designed for this, like Keras or Tensorflow.

Separately: I recommend using a convolutional network for this particular task, not a fully connected network.

Answer (score 0):

The first paragraph in [this tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/OptimizationStochasticGradientDescent/), explains it pretty well.

Also the time complexity will not grow linearly if you increase the size of your network. It will grow squared and so will the number of parameters.